# assigning command result printed "on new session" to variable

Tags: bash, aws

I have a bash script that among other things executes this command:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket my-bucket-name --output text
```

that recovers a list of items and prints them in "a new session" on the screen. It looks like that calls another command to print the result. It displays part of the results and the ":" at the end of the list, where you are able to press "space" or "q". When you "q" (quit) it displays back the "original" terminal content.

I would like to know how to identify this "printing command" executed by aws and how to be able to store it in a variable. I have tried redirecting it into a file (`> file`) or assigning the command output to a variable ( `output=$(command)` ), but neither works.

Comment: Based on your description, it sounds like the `aws s3api` command is using a *pager* - see [Use AWS CLI pagination options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-pagination.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use the `--no-cli-pager` option of the `aws` command line client to disable that pager.

```
yourvar="$(aws --no-cli-pager s3cli …)"
```

I haven't checked, but it's totally possible that it integrates its own pager instead of e.g. using `less`. But it might also just use `less`, which is a common choice for this kind of thing.

Comment: it worked, than you!